# Can not display correct time on my device (iPhone)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

On the Unity3d editor I get the correct time but since daylight saving time is active the time on my device (iPhone during current testing) is showing DST - 1, pre DST.

I have tried several different solutions but not been able to get this work. The last test I did I used this code:

```
string deviceTimeZoneId = TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id;
    TimeZoneInfo deviceTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(deviceTimeZoneId);

    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

    DateTime deviceTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(currentTime, deviceTimeZone);

    if (deviceTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(deviceTime))
    {
        deviceTime = deviceTime.AddHours(1);
    }

    txt_RealTime.text = deviceTime.ToString("HH:mm");
```

It still display current time -1 hour on the device but not in the editor.

Is there anyone nice that can help me get this in order as it is the only current problem I have in my beta test.

Comment: So your issue is that you have different times on different devices?

Comment: yes it is, is perfect in editor

Comment: Did you try calculating without DST?

Comment: I did and solved it somewhat manually but I do not understand why this happen?

Comment: So you calculated without dst and it worked?